# What went astray in this code — based on Proofwiki — but I tried to edit?

Tags: support, mathjax

I'm trying to fix the code for [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628834/proof-e-is-irational-choice-of-sign-of-m-n-e-and-uncanny-step) from http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Number_is_Irrational
I can't see what went astray. I didn't just copy and paste  this code
—   I shortened it. Furthermore, can you please expose how you determined the problem?

Multiplying both sides by $n!$ $\color{red}{\text{Why — eliminate the denominators? Please edit this if wrong}}$:

$\displaystyle \frac m n n! = n! \sum_{i \mathop = 0}^\infty \frac 1 {i!} = \left({\frac{n!}{0!} + \frac{n!}{1!} + \frac{n!}{2!} + \cdots + \frac {n!}{n!}}\right) + \left({\frac{n!}{\left({n + 1}\right)!} + \frac{n!}{\left({n + 2}\right)!} + \frac{n!}{\left({n + 3}\right)!} + \cdots}\right)$

$
{{eqn | l=m \left({n - 1}\right)! - \left({\frac{n!}{0!} + \frac{n!}{1!} + \frac{n!}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{n!}{n!} }
      =\frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 2}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 2}\right) \left({n + 3}\right)} + \cdots
      |=\frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 1}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 1}\right)} + \cdots
      =\sum_{i \mathop = 0}^\infty \left ({\frac 1 {n+1} }\right)^{\left({i + 1}\right)}
      r=\frac{\frac 1 {n+1} } {1 - \frac 1 {n+1} } = \frac 1 n < 1\) from [[Sum of Infinite Geometric Progression]] \(
      | c=
}}
$

This is what I want to work out —

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is the second **\left(** after the *eqn* is unbalanced. If you remove that, most of the codes will be rendered properly as illustrated below:

$$
{{eqn | l=m \left({n - 1}\right)! - {\frac{n!}{0!} + \frac{n!}{1!} + \frac{n!}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{n!}{n!} }
      =\frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 2}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 2}\right) \left({n + 3}\right)} + \cdots
      |=\frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 1}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 1}\right)} + \cdots
      =\sum_{i \mathop = 0}^\infty \left ({\frac 1 {n+1} }\right)^{\left({i + 1}\right)}
      r=\frac{\frac 1 {n+1} } {1 - \frac 1 {n+1} } = \frac 1 n < 1\) from [[Sum of Infinite Geometric Progression]] \(
      | c=
}}$$

Comment: Thanks — how'd you notice the problem? Did you use some program or checker?

Comment: @DwayneE.Pouiller Purely based on experience. Unbalanced **\left**, **\right** and dangling **&** are some of the most common mistakes that screw up one's formatting.

Comment: Thanks a lot — will see to them.